# I Can't Echo Session Variable in PHP althought it's very simple

Tags: php

i feel dumb (like always)

So i have website, and finally trying to move what i build on localhost to my website but the hell that's not working somehow. Finally after research what i get is my session is not working.

So i try make simple php session on my website and it's somehow the session variable not setting like i want.

This is the example i try :

http://dofaiyah.com/shop/login/  << access this, when clcik submit, i make  $_SESSION["token"] = "green" and then redirect to index (http://dofaiyah.com/shop/index.php) and echo that session.

But that's not working.

My code is very simple

On Login

```
    <?php 
session_start();


if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {  
    $_SESSION["token"] = "green"; 
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    //echo $_SESSION["token"]; 
}


?>



<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

On index

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
   //header("Location: login");
   }
else {
    $_SESSION['views'] = 1;}

echo "views = ". $_SESSION['token']; 


?>
```

Like what i'm missing? i really don't know.

//////

Edit : yes i'm already try to excecute it at my localhost and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19692734/11430357

Comment: yes i already check that, and i also use xampp and ampps to test and they're work perfectly.

Comment: already echo the phpinfo but i can't find register globals one...where?

Comment: That's answer is from 2013, `register_globals` has been removed from PHP 5.4.0

Comment: what make me furious is the fact they're normal when on my localhost hh. Is there something wrong with my cpanel or what.

Comment: Since your code is running fine on localhost, it's likely your server's issue. It's best that you contact your webmaster

Comment: I tryed you code on my server and it works perfectly... Its on your server's issue, like catcon says "try to contact your webmasters"

Answer (score -2):

On Login You are redirecting before  to show the session value .

Comment: $_SESSION["token"] = "green"; 
  header("Location: ../index.php");

nah i'm inserting variable first and redirect after that. I'm already testing it on my localhost and work perfectly.